# Unexpected behaviour from clojure.java.api.Clojure

Tags: java, api, clojure, conditional-statements

I've been experimenting with `clojure.java.api` introduced in *Clojure 1.6.0*, as I'd like to import some Clojure functionality into my java project. Unfortunately, it is not behaving as I'd expect when I invoke the conditional functions **and** and **or** from Java.

```
IFn and = Clojure.var("clojure.core", "and");
IFn or = Clojure.var("clojure.core", "or");

-- equivalent to (and true false) in clojure
and.invoke(true,false); --> returns true rather than false???   

-- equivalent to (or true false) in clojure
or.invoke(true,false); --> returns null rather than true???

-- equivalent to (and true true) in clojure
and.invoke(true,true); --> returns true as expected

-- equivalent to (or true true) in clojure    
or.invoke(true,true); --> returns null rather than true???
```

I can't believe this is a bug, so I suspect I'm missing something fairly fundamental relating to the API. Whatever the cause, it has left me rather confused. If anyone can offer an explanation I'd be very grateful.

Thanks,

Matt.

Answer (score 3):

`and` and `or` are macros and the rules for evaluation are somewhat different for them. For example, when on the Clojure REPL, trying to evaluate `and` throws `CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't take value of a macro: #'clojure.core/and, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:0:0)`.

There should be a way to use them through `clojure.java.api.Clojure` though, but I haven't figured it out for now since macros need to be compiled in order to work.

The next best option I can think of is using `eval` but I'm not sure that is something you want to do. On the other hand, why use `and`/`or` when the good old `&&`/`||` Java operators exist?

Answer (score 1):

`and` and `or` are macros, not functions. They expect two or more forms (so a clojure.lang.IPersistentList of symbols or nested IPersistentLists, I think) which they expand into a combination of `let*` and `if`.

```
(clojure.walk/macroexpand-all '(and true false))
;returns:
(let* [and__3941__auto__ true] 
      (if and__3941__auto__ 
        false
        and__3941__auto__))
```

You may be better off making a clojure fn which uses `and` and `or` on your behalf. For instance, to take them over a collection:

```
(defn reduce-and [values]
  (reduce #(and %1 %2) values))
(defn reduce-or [values]
  (reduce #(or %1 %2) values))
```

Comment: Take into account that `reduce-and` and `reduce-or` loose the short-circuit semantics of the original `or` and `and`, which is something you sometimes count on.